# Multiple column selection in columnar database

Tags: sql, database, indexing

I am just understanding the difference between row based and column based databases. I know their benefits but I have few questions.
Let's say I have a table with 3 columns - col1, col2 and col3. I want to fetch all col2, col3 pairs where col3 matches particular value. Let's say column values are stored in disk like below.

> Block1        = col1
> Block2,Block3 = col2
> Block4        = col3

1. My understanding is that column value along with row id information will be stored in a block. Eg: (Block4 -> apple:row_2, banana:row_1). Am I correct?
2. Are values in the block sorted by column value? Eg: (Block4 -> apple:row_2, banana:row_1 instead of Block4 -> banana:row_1, apple:row_2). If not, how does filtering or search work without compromising the performance?
3. Assuming values in the block are sorted based on column value, how does corresponding col2 values will be filtered based on row ids fetched from Block4 ? Does it require linear search then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of a columnar database is to improve performance for *read* queries by limiting the IO only to those columns used in the query.  It does this by separating the columns into separate storage spaces.

A naive form of a columnar database would store one or a set of columns with a primary key and then use `JOIN` to bring together all the columns for a table.  Columns that are not referenced would not be included.

However, databases that provide native support for columnar databases have much more sophisticated functionality than the naive example.  Each columnar database stores data in its own way.  So, your answer depends on the particular database which you haven't specified.

They might store "blocks" of values for a column and these blocks represent (in some way) a range of rows.  So, if you are choosing 1 row from a billion row table, only the blocks with those rows need to be read.

Storing columns separately allows for enhanced functionality *at the column level*:

1. Compression.  Values with the same data type can be much more easily compressed than rows which contain different values.
2. Block statistics.  Blocks can be summarized statistically -- such as min and max values -- which can facilitate filtering.
3. Secondary data structures.  Indexes for instance can be used within blocks (and these might be akin to "sorting" the values, actually).

The cost of all this is that inserts are no longer simple, so ACID properties are trickier with a column orientation.  Because such databases are often used for decision support queries, this may not be an important limitation.

The "rows" are determined -- essentially -- by row ids.  However, the row ids may actually consist of multiple parts, such as a block id and a row-within-a-block.  This allows the store to use, say, 4 bytes for each component but not be limited to 4 billion rows.

Reconstructing rows between different columns is obviously a critical piece of functionality for any such database.  In the "naive" example, this is handled via `JOIN` algorithms.  However, specialized data structures would clearly have more specific approaches.  Storing the data essentially in "row order" would be a typical solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can understand that it will save lot of IO for tables with multiple columns (say more than 20) while the query require only few number(say 4) of columns. I am wondering how filtering will be performed once the particular block(with all column values) is read. Won't it take lot of in memory operation if they are stored in row or column order depending on the query use case?

Comment: @explorer . . . In general, the values from the block are going to be read in row order, with the row id, so they can be easily merged with values from other columns.  Does it take a lot of memory?  Well, a lot less memory than data pages that store all columns in them.  But if you are accessing all columns, then it is probably a bit less efficient in general (well, the column-specific compression can make up for that).